How to define a custom JSX namespace with verbatimModuleSyntax?
I am building my own TSX-based renderer for a specific runtime which is not web. I have two files in my library code:

// h.ts
import { type JSXInternal } from './jsx.js';

export function h(props: any): any {}

export namespace h {
  // ERROR HERE...
  export import JSX = JSXInternal;
}

// jsx.ts
export namespace JSXInternal {
  export interface IntrinsicElements {
    foo: any;
    div: any;
  }
}

However, I cannot seem to get it to work without turning off the verbatimModuleSyntax flag. Is there any solution to use this problem?
